# How to refer to div by li element outside that div

Tags: jquery, html, refer

on the begining I have to admit that my knowledge about programming is quite basic. I don't understand everything so maybe my question can look little lame but still my ideas run out and I need to ask.

I've used an Slide Elements tutorial and add some sliding Div in to my webside, everything works fine but in this tutorial author used a button element inside parent div and on click inner div slides. I want to use a li element from my navigation section that is outside that divs but i dont know how change the script code to keep the animation in that div. 
Basically it looks:

HTML:

```
    <ul id="navigation">
 <li class="about"><a title="A" href="#" > </a></li>
 <li class="search"><a title="P" href="#" ></a></li>
 <li class="photos"><a title="G" href="#" ></a></li>
 <li class="rssfeed"><a title="U" href="#" ></a></li>
 <li class="contact"><a title="K" href="#" ></a></li>
</ul>

    <div id="IDcontent" class="slide" >
<button>slide it</button>
<div class="inner"  style="margin-left: 100%"> test </div>
</div>
```

I manage to change script code that an li element triggers a click action not the button, but after click, it not slide the div but it slides a next li element.

SCRIPT CODE:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li').click(function() {
    var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
    $marginLefty.animate({
      marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
        $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
        0
    });
  });
});

  </script>
```

Any sugestions ?

Big Thanks!

Comment: The problem you're going to have is that the LI you click has no relationship to the stack of DIVs that you're sliding. Please show more HTML for the slider divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line of code,

```
var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
```

the next li element after what was clicked on is animated since you later do $marginLefty.animate().  If you want to animate the div, you should set marginLefty to the div element.  So replace that line with:

```
var $marginLefty = $('.inner');
```

To find out which li was clicked, you can do

```
// $(this) refers to the element that was clicked
$liClass = $(this).attr("class")
```

inside the click handler.  Then you can change the content of the div based which li was clicked, and by using the html() function.  For example,

```
var content;
if($liClass == 'about'){
 content = 'about clicked';
}
else if($liClass == 'search'){
    content = 'search clicked';
}
//more code here
//more code here
$marginLefty.html(content);
```

You can find more information about .attr() and .html() over here:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/ and http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Big thanks, i was shure that problem was in that line but didn't know how to bite it :) But still there is an small error in youre answer. 

That Var should not pointing to #IDcontent

var $marginLefty = $('#IDcontent');  

In that case it works when I define it as .inner class object. 

Thanks for answer, with it I've manage to solve it out.

Comment: Can I use little bit more of Your kindness and ask You about modification I would like to apply ? I've got 2 subjects:

1) The sliding animaton works now like on/off button, 1 click div is sliding in , second click div is sliding out, i wanted to change it that when i click next li element present div is automaticly sliding  out and slide in with new content. 
2) And that content is the second part. Could You give me some tip or point some tutorial how can I change that Div content by clicking  on specify li element. Should I create diferetn Div and show only that one i need?

Big thanks !:)

Comment: sure, see the edit to my answer.  In the future, when you have another part to your problem, you can ask it as another question.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the last part of your comment.  Creating different divs and showing the one you need would work too.  http://api.jquery.com/hide/  http://api.jquery.com/show/ If you have to make more than 2 or 3 divs, though, you might be better of just using the html() function

Comment: Thanks again, Your answers where inspiring for me ;) Specialy that If/else helps me ... i'm an old school web designer .. using old techniques .. but after that few days digging through all that codes and syntax I've discover whole new world .. It's unlimited! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#navigation li').click(function() {
        var $marginLefty = $('a', this);
        $marginLefty.animate({
          marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
            $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
            0
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're wanting a LI element to do the same thing the button element is doing? You can just trigger a click on the button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li').click(function() {
      $('#IDcontent').find('button').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Your button element will need to remain on the page. This will basically run any code attached to the button's click event - whenever you click ANY of your LI elements. You can set this up to work on only 1 list element by changing the selector:

```
  $('#navigation li.about').click(function() {
   ...
  });
```

That will attach this functionality to the li class="about" element only.

This works if you're planning on leaving the button on your page. You can simply hide the button in CSS, but that's a bit sloppy. If you decide to remove the button altogether, simply find the Javascript code that the button is using. It will look like this:

```
$('#IDcontent button').click(function(){ ... });
```

or something similar. Then just move that code inside the button's click event into the click event for the list element.